# Bitlocker windows data partition broken after partition manager apply

Tags: partitioning, encryption, data-recovery, fdisk, gdisk

I was trying to install ubuntu on my laptop. I tried to move some partitions and extend other ones. One of them was a data partition, that was partitioned using Windows, so it was probably controlled by Windows. There were a lot of data there, and now after the partition software finished, I can see that the partitions have not changed.. or better they have changed but only in a way: the data partition now does seem not recognised any more. In the partition manager software there is only the option to delete or to recover it into a hard disk.

I tried to see the situation on WIndows.. well, partition looks "unformatted".. any hints?

[EDIT]
This installing the last OS version

[edit 2]
There were these partitions, to simplify: 
part1 is NTFS Windows   -> 90 GB, 
part2 is NTFS data   -> 60 GB,
part3 was previous Linux version  -> 100 GB

I then used the partition tool to do this:

first step:

```
part1 (NTFS Windows) shrinked to 70 GB, 
free space   ->  20 GB 
part2 (NTFS data)  -> 60 GB,
part3 (Linux)  -> 100 GB
```

second step:

```
part1 (NTFS Windows) shrinked to 70 GB, 
part2 (NTFS data) moved to the old free space and increased of 10 GB  -> 70 GB,
part3 (Linux) moved to the end of the previous partition -> 110 GB
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your issue and I'm lacking some information. The broken partition, did you shrink it? Or did you format it? Were you able to finish Ubuntu's installation? A screenshot of Gparted or Windows disk manager would really help!

Comment: Hi Santiago, thank you for your reply! I'll edit the question to let you understand thanks!

Comment: I've seen your edit, thanks for updating, now I gotta ask, the non-responding partition is the 70gb one?

Comment: yes @Santiago it's part2 . I'm trying to use EaseUs Partition Master Free Edition to see if I can do something.. but I would have preferred another way

Comment: I was hoping for it to be ext4, that way it made sense Windows didn't recognise it, but being NTFS is really weird, you should be able to read/write from either Ubuntu or Windows. My guess, there may have been a problem while extending your storage or something relatively similar. If you can upload a Gparted or Windows Disk Manager screenshot it would be great, that way we could discard or not any possible recovery.

Comment: I can't do a screenshot now as it is copying a partition.. just in case I'm doing the clone of this  (now) unformatted data partition in another HD.. something I had to due before.. I hope to learn the lesson, and this this will remind other people to do it as well eheh